# How can I dispatch from child components in React Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

My server has code like this:

`<ReactRedux.Provider store={store}><Layout defaultStore={JSON.stringify(store.getState())}/></ReactRedux.Provider>`

`<Layout>` obviously has more components which nest more.

I have a class like this deeper down:

```
import React from 'react';

export default React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    var classes = [
      'js-select-product',
      'pseudo-link'
    ];

    if (this.props.selected) {
      classes.push('bold');
    }

    return (
      <li className="js-product-selection">
        <span onClick={this.props.onClick} className={classes.join(' ')} data-product={this.props.id}>{this.props.name}</span>
      </li>
    );
  }
});
```

What I really want to do rather than `this.props.onClick` is dispatch an event to [set state in a reducer](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html). I've been some things online about context but I've gotten mixed reviews as that feature was or wasn't going away.

**EDIT**
I see this [connect method](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) but I could have sworn I'd read not to use `connect` in children components.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You're getting too caught up on children components. You should structure your app so that you have connected components and non-connected components. Non-connected components should be stateless, pure functions essentially, that take in all their requirements via props. Connected components should use the `connect` function to map redux state to props and redux dispatcher to props, and then be responsible for passing those props to child components.

You might have lots of connected components in an app, and lots of non-connected components. [This post](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0#.l3ds39hwv) (by the creator of redux) discusses it in more detail, and talks about non-connected (dumb) components being responsible for actual display of UI, and connected (smart) components being responsible for composing non-connected components.

An example might be (using some newer syntax):

```
class Image extends React {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.props.name}</h1>
        <img src={this.props.src} />
        <button onClick={this.props.onClick}>Click me</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class ImageList extends React {
  render() {
    return (
      this.props.images.map(i => <Image name={i.name} src={i.src} onClick={this.props.updateImage} />)
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    images: state.images,
  };
};
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    updateImage: () => dispatch(updateImageAction()),
  };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ImageList);
```

In this example, `ImageList` is a connected component and `Image` is a non-connected component.

Comment: "Connected components should use the connect function to map" the redux dispatcher to props. In other words pass the dispatcher as a prop to the child e.g. <ChildComponent dispatcher={this.props.dispatch} />

Comment: @jeffora The problem with this answer is that you assume you can just load all of your dispatch actions in the "parent". But it doesnt address OPs question of whether connecting child components to redux dispatch is an anti pattern or not

Comment: @AlxVallejo Hey, thanks for the comment. I believe the post I linked to in the answer does address the OP's question, indicating that connecting child components is *not* an anti-pattern. And as you say I am assuming that a parent component can load all the dispatch actions that it needs, but I'm not assuming a *single* parent component for an app. The "parent" might be really low level, but its concern should only be connecting to the dispatcher and passing data to child components, and the children's concern is only rendering input data. Also, this is 2 years old now and things change fast

Answer (score 0):

There used to be advice to the effect to try to limit the components that you connect. See for example:

https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/419

https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/419#issuecomment-178850728

Anyway, that's really more useful for delegating a slice of state to a component. You can do that if it makes sense for your situation, or if you don't want to pass down a callback that calls `dispatch()` you can pass the store or dispatch down the hierarchy if you want.

Comment: So really connect it to component like example `export default connect()(MyComponent)` and then dispatch from there? Forget whatever I remember from 6 months back? :)