# How to pass action to child in react using redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have container and component.
How to pass action (or?) to child components?

My container that handles actions

```
class HeaderContainer extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { index } = this.props;

    return (
        <Header index={index} onChangeIndex={...}/>
    );
  }
}

const putStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    index: state.schedule.index
  };
};

export default connect(putStateToProps, null)(HeaderContainer)
```

My component that renders data from container

```
const Header = ({ ...props }) => {
  const { index, onChangeIndex} = props;

  return (
      <AppBar position="static" color="default">
        <Tabs value={index} onChange={onChangeIndex}>
          ...
        </Tabs>
      </AppBar>
  )
};
```

There is my action

```
export const changeIndex = (index) => {
  return {
    type: SCHEDULE_CHANGE_INDEX,
    payload: index
  }
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I dispatch from child components in React Redux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36559661/how-can-i-dispatch-from-child-components-in-react-redux)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class HeaderContainer extends React.Component {
  handleChangeIndex = (event) => {
    const index = event.target.value; // You may need to change this line
    this.dispatch(changeIndex(index));
  } 

  render() {
    const { index } = this.props;

    return (
        <Header index={index} onChangeIndex={handleChangeIndex}/>
    );
  }
}
```